# Notification div is not showing upon matching the fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was trying to match the text box text to the dropdown text. When it matched it select the option from the dropdown. I want to show the notication when the text does not matched from the dropdown and when it matched it should hide the notification. Problem is i am not able to hide it when it matched. Here is my jquery. This is what i tried so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txt_scheme").keyup(function(){
    var valueFromText=$("#scheme option").filter(function(i,option)
                                                 {
      return $(option).text().toLowerCase()==$("#txt_scheme").val().toLowerCase();
    }).val();


    if ($("#txt_scheme").val() == '' || $('#scheme option:selected').text().toLowerCase() == $("#txt_scheme").val()){
      $('#notify').hide(500);
    }
    else{
      $('#notify').show(500);
    }
    $("#scheme").val(valueFromText);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Scheme**</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" name="scheme" id="scheme">
      <option value="A">QC code</option>
      <option value="B">Analyte</option>
      <option value="B">Assay Value</option> 
      <option value="D">Assigned Value</option>  
      <option value="E">STANDARDDEVIATION</option>  
      <option value="F">ACCEPTABLEMIN</option>   
      <option value="G">ACCEPTABLEMAX</option>   
      <option value="H">Sample ID</option>
      <option value="I">Date</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_scheme" name="txt_scheme" placeholder="Or Type here">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id='notify' style="display: none; width: 50%">
      <strong>Alert!</strong> Nothing matched select from dropdown
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just to put the selection :

```
$("#scheme").val(valueFromText);
```

Before the condition, so the `$('#scheme option:selected').text()` will return the right text to check.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txt_scheme").keyup(function(){
    var valueFromText=$("#scheme option").filter(function(i,option){
      return $(option).text().toLowerCase()==$("#txt_scheme").val().toLowerCase();
    }).val();

    $("#scheme").val(valueFromText);

    if ($("#txt_scheme").val() == '' || $('#scheme option:selected').text().toLowerCase() == $("#txt_scheme").val()){
      $('#notify').hide(500);
    }
    else{
      $('#notify').show(500);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Scheme**</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" name="scheme" id="scheme">
      <option value="A">QC code</option>
      <option value="B">Analyte</option>
      <option value="B">Assay Value</option> 
      <option value="D">Assigned Value</option>  
      <option value="E">STANDARDDEVIATION</option>  
      <option value="F">ACCEPTABLEMIN</option>   
      <option value="G">ACCEPTABLEMAX</option>   
      <option value="H">Sample ID</option>
      <option value="I">Date</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_scheme" name="txt_scheme" placeholder="Or Type here">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id='notify' style="display: none; width: 50%">
      <strong>Alert!</strong> Nothing matched select from dropdown
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh man! why i did not ponder on that thing i tried only to put different things in condition and ignore this! Thankx man :) i dont know why i do these dumb mistakes.